# Does anyone know the difference about ".*\s*" and "[.\s]*" in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match two words that usually are joined with a dash '-' and sometimes 0, 1 or 2 white spaces. I decided to use the following Regex pattern to solve the problem: `[.\s]*`

However that pattern does not match this case: "word1-word2" 
The following pattern solves the problem:  `.*\s*` for all the cases.

All the cases: 
word1-word2
word1word2
word1 word2
word1  word2

I am currently using the second pattern, however I would like to know the subtle diference between them. If it is of any help I am using C#.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `.` is in `[]`, it matches the literal character `.`.

When it is used outside a `[]`, it matches any character except for a new line.

You may see the explanation here:

- `[.\s]*` - https://regex101.com/r/cJ4kB9/1
- `.*\s*` - https://regex101.com/r/cJ4kB9/2

Though, you may consider using `\b\w*\s*-\s*\w*\b` for your case. See the example at https://regex101.com/r/cJ4kB9/3

Answer (score 0):

You regex is basically saying:

```
.  // Match any character
*  // Zero or more times
\s // Matches any white space including space, tab, form-feed, etc.
*  // Those white spaces, tabs etc. can occur Zero or more times.
```

So by the looks of it, it basically fails to identify if there is a 2nd word next to it. It would also validate against:

`word1 -`

`word1-`

etc.

Comment: The regex actually matches *any* string through the ample use of `*`.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing that

Answer (score 0):

`[^\s]+[\s-]*[^\s]*`

A couple of non-whitespace characters, followed by 0 or more whitespace/dash combos, followed by a couple of non-whitespaces again.